# iOS / Android & hammer.js: Events stop when touched HTML Element is removed from the DOM

Tags: javascript, touch, dom-events, hammer.js

I have a big problem with hammer.js on iOS / Android devices: There seems to be an issue with events and removed HTML elements. Say we have a container, on which we use hammer.js with a touch and pan handlers. Inside we have a HTML element, which we start dragging. When the element is removed during some logic inside the handlers, no event will be fired anymore, even if the finger is still on the device and moving. Desktop browsers don't show this annoying behaviour.

Here is a little jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/npowuf15/20/ ...

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="steady"></div>
    <div id="willBeDeleted"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#steady {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background: green;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
    -webkit-user-drag: none; 
}

#willBeDeleted {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
    -webkit-user-drag: none; 
}
```

JS:

```
Hammer(document.getElementById('wrapper'))
.on('hammer.input', function(evt) {
    if (evt.isFirst) {
        console.log('touch', evt.target.id);
        if (evt.target.id === 'willBeDeleted') {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $(evt.target).remove()
            }, 500);
        }        
    }
})
.on('panstart', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log('panstart', evt.target.id);
})
.on('panmove', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log('panmove', evt.target.id);    
})
.on('panend', function(evt) {
    console.log('panend', evt.target.id);
});
```

when you debug this on iOS, you can see, how the events stop when you try to move the finger after touching the box with the id "willBeDeleted" - because it will be deleted after half a second.

Is this really expected behaviour? Any suggestions?

Comment: Your fiddle works for me in iOS (iOS 7)! All `console.logs` are showing up correctly.